# How to open Google Authenticator from a link?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I'm developing a website that requires a 2FA. We already permit to users to set it by scanning a QR Code shown in our configuration page.

My question is a bit more tricky. **How can I permit user to open the app if he opens the page from mobile browser, ie. navigating from the phone with the Authenticator app installed?**

I already have the logic to understand if the user is on mobile or not, but I don't find any solution that can replace the QRCode since the user cannot use the mobile camera in that case (he is using the phone to net on my website!).

I was searching the possibility to create a link that is recognised by an authenticator app (Google Authenticator or Microsoft Authenticator) but I didn't find a solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

After some research and trial, I found the link I was searching for.
In Google Authenticator (or any other app), the account are listed in the form:

- Amazon(my@amazon.com)

  - 123455
- Google(me@gmail.com)

  - 455234
- Issuer(email)

  - 554645
- AnotherCode

  - 142414

In order to generate a new entry without scanning the QRCode, a link in the form of:

```
otpauth://totp/dev@it.com?secret=123abc&issuer=StackOverflow
```

has to be opened. For instance, the link above results in the following entry:

- StackOverflow(dev@it.com)

The link is opened by the phone using the installed Authenticator app.

Comment: is it more that this link will open the authenticator app? ie from an app or website.

Comment: Yes, depends on the default app but in general yes